# How to make a random sampling of 20% of records in Tableau?

Tags: random, tableau-api

In Tableau 9.2, is it possible to generate a random sample of records?  If so, how could I do this?  Say I have a field called Field1, then I intend to only select 20% of the records.  So far, I have [found](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1474) how to a generate random integer in Tableau, though it is bewildering that Tableau [does not](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/2046) already have a function for this:

**Random Seed**

```
(DATEPART('second', NOW()) + 1) * (DATEPART('minute', NOW()) + 1) * (DATEPART('hour', NOW()) + 1) * (DATEPART('day', NOW()) + 1)
```

**Random Number**

```
((PREVIOUS_VALUE(MIN([Seed])) * 1140671485 + 12820163) % (2^24))
```

**Random Int**

```
INT([Random Number] / (2^24) * [Random Upper Limit]) + 1
```

So how could I create a calculated field to only show random records that make up 20% of Field1?

Comment: Showing my age here: Knuth TAoCP Vol 2 Algorithm 3.4.2 S

Comment: i just noticed that in 10.0, there's an option for x% sampling with data extracts. If using 10.0 is an option for you, I'd suggest trying that.

Comment: Sam M: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue through the back-end in my MS Access database with the following MS Access SQL Query within a MS Access VBA macro I made:

```
    value1 = "some_value"
    fieldName = "[my_field_name]"
    sqlQuery = "SELECT [my_table].* " & _
                 " INTO new_table_name" & _
                 " FROM [my_table] " & _
                 " WHERE [some_field] = '" & value1 & "'" & _
                 " ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*" & fieldName & ")*Time())"

    Debug.Print sqlQuery
    CurrentDb.Execute sqlQuery
```

I ended up deciding that something like this would be best left to the back-end and to leave the visual analytics to Tableau.

Answer (score 2):

When you make an extract, there is a dialog panel where you can filter records and specify rolling up to visible dimensions.

For at least some data sources, you can also specify a limit of the number of records (say grab the first 2000 records) or a random percentage (say, 10% of the records)

Then you can work with the small extract quickly to design you viz, and then remove the extract or refresh with all the data when you are ready. I don't think every data source supports the random selection though.

Comment: Thanks, it allows me to select a "Top" 20%, however I am not seeing an option for a random 20%.  Do you know if something like this is possible?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS Access 2010

Comment: Some databases (or their drivers) support the random percentage filter when building extracts, some don't. MySQL does for example. MS Access apparently doesn't. You could either take the most recent N records, or even define a calculated field that sort-of randomly selects records and use that to filter what is included in the extract. Say only include records whose transaction id is divisible by 5.

Answer (score 2):

There is a random number function ins Tableau, but it is hidden and doesn't appear on the list of available functions.

It is "random()". It generates a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1.

It isn't documented but it works. See, for example, this previous answer: [how to generate pseudo random numbers and row-count in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869143/how-to-generate-pseudo-random-numbers-and-row-count-in-tableau)

Comment: The issue is, I don't know how to use this to select a random 20% of records in Tableau.

Comment: One reason random() is undocumented is that it is only available for some data sources.